# Fire only one event in JQuery

Tags: jquery

How do you make JQuery fire only the last event handler you set? For example, in this [test case](http://jsfiddle.net/ms2RP/), I want only launch the last *alert* ("world").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it

```
$("#test").click(function() { alert('hello'); return false; });
// Before the last event handler.
$("#test").unbind("click");
$("#test").click(function() { alert('world'); return false; });
```

Answer (score 5):

You can unbind the previous event handlers and attach only the one you want.

```
element.unbind(event).bind(event,eventHandler);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use jquery [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
$("#tesr").one("click", function() {
  alert("This will be displayed only once.");
});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ms2RP/1/

Comment: Your answer is irrelevant to the question..and might confuse people who come here.